# ProgressDialog onUpdate database android get "Unabled to add window"

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I launch TaskAsync for "align new fields" in "public void onUpgrade database"
Wend i arrived on ProgressDialog.show (inside a TaskAsync) i received this error:

**"Unabled to add window - token null is not for an application**"

Why?...onUpgrade is not a Activity...i have pass (for Context) a .getApplicationContext() but same error.
I try delete all istruction for "progressdialog" it's work perferct.

Which context should I use in the "On Upgrade" event of the sqlite database?

Comment: Should not use application context for `dialog`

Comment: Dialogs can only take Activity Contexts, because they need to be attached to the Activity's window.

Comment: Uhmmm, for heavy database operations sqllite force to use a task... but if you use a task in a on Upgrade() you can't  show a progress...it's nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, don't use `getApplicationContext()`, use `ACTIVITY_NAME.this` for the context.

Comment: Uhmmm, not exist a valid active activity wend onUpgrade() run...now i run my UpgradeTableTask in Activity Main onCreate(), now i put a global variable in onUpgrade()  and set launchTaskUpdate=true, not another good Solutions for now.... but i try.